# Django fetch manytomany values as list

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

```
class Groups:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User:
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Groups)
```

i need user details with groupname as list not as separate records.

```
User.objects.values('firstname','lastname', 'group__name')
```

While i'm querying like above, i'm getting like this

> <QuerySet [{'firstname': 'Market', 'lastname': 'Cloud', 'group__name':
> 'Group 5'}, {'firstname': 'Market', 'lastname': 'Cloud',
> 'group__name': 'Group 4'}]>

but i want like this

> <QuerySet [{'firstname': 'Market', 'lastname': 'Cloud', 'group__name':
> ['Group 5', 'Group 4']}]>

is there a way, i can query like this without doing separate query.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postgres you can use [ARRAY_AGG function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html). In Django ORM like below:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

User.objects \
    .annotate(list_of_group_names=ArrayAgg('group__name')) \
    .order_by('id').distinct() \
    .values('firstname', 'lastname', 'list_of_group_names')
```

**Note:** `distinct` is useful, because joining tables can result in duplicates